# How to write a script to verify Jboss just started

Tags: bash, logs, jboss

I have to write a script to run JBoss and also verify and inform JBoss has just started in system startup. Below code is to related to verifying part.
Please correct logical and syntax mistakes I have done.

Log record I am `grep`ing:

> 2017-10-27 12:04:13,933 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 1m:1s:804ms

```
!/bin/bash

maxLoops=30 numLines=200 timeToSleep=3 success=0 Server_Log=$(/path_for_log/server.log)

        for (( try=0; try < maxLoops; ++try ));
        do
           atail=`tail -n $numLines $Server_Log | grep "Started" | awk {'print $12'}`

        if [[ $atail == "Started" ]]
                then
                        success=1
                        break
              fi
                sleep $timeToSleep
        done
        if (( success ));
        then
                echo "Jboss started successfully"
        else
                echo "successful starting of Jboss is not ensured"

fi
```

Please find the error below that I am getting while executing the script 
as root:

```
$ ./verify_jboss.sh:
 line 3: /log_path/server.log: Permission denied
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream

Answer (score 1):

If possible check if Jboss is listening on the port:

```
if curl -Is http://localhost:80/ > /dev/null
then
   echo OK
else
   echo FAIL
fi
```

You just need one external program: [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)

**Edit**:

Another approach is to test for a specific content, say `Contact` on the web page. Only if the webserver is running and there is a connection to the database, it will respond correctly.

```
if grep -qc "Contact" <(curl -s http://localhost/)
then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

The construction `<(curl ...)` *(Process Substitution)* will be seen by `grep` as a file. `curl` has option `-s` for silent to avoid transfer progress. `grep` has option `-qc` to suppress output and count the occurrence of the matched text. If one or more count of `Contact` the result is OK (exit code 0).

Comment: Thank for your reply ,but I think it doesn't work . because even jboss stopped, Still port 80 is Listen by httpd service   , Because We are starting jboss by manual script with nohup

Answer (score 0):

You could try making request and then checking for some specific content:

```
curl_result=$(curl -Is https://www.yoururl.com)

if  echo "$curl_result" | grep  "some_text_generated_by_JBOSS"; then
  echo "Server ok" 
fi
```